# Нужно ли тире, если не использовать "так" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Если я не ошибаюсь, то перед "так" в данном предложении ставится запятая:

*Как получу свою тетрадь, так сразу всё вышлю.*

Изменится ли ситуация, если опустить "так"?

*Как получу свою тетрадь — сразу всё вышлю.*

Comment: @oleedd
Очень тянет, знаете ли...  А вы не дадите свой ответ, чтобы можно было четко видеть ваше мнение по элементарнейшему вопросу?

Comment: А вы за меня не решайте,  please :)  Там и другие проблемы есть (но это я так думаю).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‟Как” и ‟так” – это части одного союза ‟как так”, поэтому между предложениями ставится запятая. Что по поводу того, если убрать ‟так”. Есть [такое правило](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142), которое гласит, что когда придаточная часть идёт перед главной и когда пауза длиннее, чем обычно между главной и придаточной, то ставится тире. В данном случая, я считаю, пауза обычная, поэтому ставится запятая.

Но возможно также тире при особом произношении, то есть когда более длинная пауза всё же есть. Например, если один человек не высылает деньги другому и тот раздражён.

> – Когда ты уже вышлешь мне деньги?
> – Как получу свою тетрадь – сразу всё вышлю.

**Почему я считаю ответ Sharon тем самым, чем я назвал его первый раз:**

**Серьёзные претензии:**

1. Я, конечно, не лексикограф, но, на мой взгляд, слово ‟взаимообусловленность” означает взаимную обусловленность, то есть А влияет на Б, а Б влияет на А. А здесь, получается, когда он получит тетрадь, то сразу вышлет, а когда вышлет, то получит тетрадь? Так выходит? И даже если бы она была. В таком предложении будет взаимная обусловленность: ‟Когда изменяется состояние человека, изменяется отношение к вещам”. И что, если бы была взаимообусловленность?! На что это вообще влияет?! Одного меня раздражает, когда пишут подобный бред?! Такие вещи могут писать в школьных учебниках, и при этом большинство школьников не поймут, что автор учебника просто здесь бред написал и на это не следует обращать внимание. Одному мне кажется, что это абсолютно неприемлемо?!
2. У предложения в вопросе возможно две интонации. Если оно произносится в обычной бытовой ситуации в виде сухой информации или инструкции, то здесь определённо запятая. Это как предложения: ‟Когда он придёт, сразу мне позвони”, ‟Когда я крикну, сразу вынеси мне деньги”.
3. ‟Как” в данном предложении – не союзное слово, союзные слова – это такие слова, которые выполняют функцию связи однородных элементов и при этом являются членами предложения, как ‟что” в предложении: ‟Он знал, что его спасёт”.
4. Что за термин ‟частица-союз”? ЛОЛ. У слов есть разные значение, некоторые из которых могут быть разных частей речи. Тогда нам нужно называть слово ‟конечно” вводное-частица.
5. Вы сказали, что привели пример из литературы (который ничего не значил бы, так как возможна двоякая интонация, и при этом ваше предложение очень кривое) и при этом выдумали предложение (иначе бы вы указали откуда оно). Это можно рассматривать как ложь.

**Лёгкие претензии:**

1. Вы написали, что есть ‟как так”, а есть ‟как так и”. А как это относится к вопросу? Что это за бесполезная информация? Рассказали бы ещё о своих племянниках.
2. То же самое про ‟как только так сразу”. Как это относится к вопросу?
3. Эти предложения: ‟Для соединения КАК…ТАК возможно наличие дополнительных структурных элементов, уточняющих грамматическое значение СПП. Это фразеологические модели разного вида, в частности в заданном предложении используется известное сочетание «как только …так сразу».” Эти предложение – ядрёный канцелярит, а сочетания ‟фразеологические модели”, ‟структурные элементы”, ‟уточняющие грамматическое значение” – это даже не термины, а лингвистические канцеляризмы.
4. По поводу термина ‟союзное соединение”. В большинстве источников это считается союзом (двойным союзом, как ‟не только, но и”). Лингвисты с минимальным здравым понимают, что не следует без необходимости плодить термины.

**Предложения из Нац. корпуса с запятой:**

> Явились грязные, усталые и такие голодные, что, как только умылись, сразу же схватились за ложки. Николай Дубов. На краю земли (1950).
>
> Но как только мы переставали двигаться, сразу же становилось нестерпимо холодно и нас начинала бить лихорадочная дрожь. Николай Дубов. На краю земли (1950).
>
> Как только девочка погасила фонарь, она сразу потеряла мальчика из виду. Н. Н. Шпанов. Связная Цзинь Фын (1935-1950).
>
> Она представляла себе, что, как только войдёт в зал бассейна, её сразу же поведут на вышку. Елена Ильина. Четвертая высота (1945).
>
> Но как только от поверхности океана мы обращаемся к его глубинам, сразу же чувствуется наша слабость. И. А. Ефремов. Атолл Факаофо (1944).
>
> Генерал, как углядел эту саблю, сразу ее ухватил. П. П. Бажов. Иванко Крылатко (1943).
>
> Как только пал достиг их, сразу взвилось длинное пламя. В. К. Арсеньев. В горах Сихотэ-Алиня (1937).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146546/discussion-on-answer-by-rumpelstiltskin-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: последние 2 примера похожи на мой случай, да и для проверяющего запятая в данном месте в итоге тоже оказалась более предпочтительным вариантом, так что...

Answer (score 4):

*(1) **Как** получу свою тетрадь, **так сразу** всё вышлю.*

*(2) **Как** получу свою тетрадь — **сразу** всё вышлю.*

Во втором предложении желательно поставить **тире/увеличить паузу.** Так слышат носители языка, в частности наличие тире предполагает автор вопроса, также из комментариев: Там резкие слова — "сразу", "всё", — они способствуют тире.

**Пояснение**

1. Союзное соединение ***КАК…ТАК*** (с придаточным в препозиции) встречается в СПП с разным значением (в том числе с усилительной частицей ***И***), например:

*Как на охоту идти, так (и) собак кормить. Как наденут венец, так и воле конец.* Значение времени, местоименная связь общего вида «когда…тогда», так — союзное слово.

*Как аукнется, так и откликнется.* Значение образа действия, местоименная связь,  ***как*** — союзное слово, ***так*** — указательное/соотносительное слово (коррелят).

2. Для соединения ***КАК…ТАК*** возможно наличие дополнительных **структурных элементов**, уточняющих грамматическое значение СПП. Это **фразеологические модели** разного вида, в частности в заданном предложении используется известное сочетание «***как только …так сразу***».
3. О сочетании «***как только …так сразу***», запятая или тире?

Здесь грамматическое значение времени (**одновременность** событий)  с дополнительным значением **условия**; только —  частица-союз, сразу —  наречие.

**Возможны следующие сочетания:**

*Как только приедешь, так сразу позвони*  (запятая).  *Как приедешь, так позвони* (запятая). *Как только приедешь, позвони* (запятая или тире). *Как  приедешь —  сразу позвони* (тире).

По слуху тире желательно в последнем варианте, иначе **взаимообусловленность** событий (при отсутствии указательного слова "так") в этом предложении не проявлена четко.

4. Таким образом, в  предложении  «***Как получУ свою тетрадь — сразу всё вЫшлю***» ставим тире. По Правилу Розенталя тире в СПП ставится для **интонационного отделения** главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. В нашем случае обратим внимание на логическое выделение **сказуемых** при такой расстановке ударений.

Можно привести пример из литературы, где при значении **взаимообусловленности** в предложении поставлено тире: "*А (если) присмотришься как следует – (то) обязательно скажешь: ничего себе «обыкновенный*».

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ от 09.06.2023 г.**

**Я укажу, откуда взят материал.** Это очень известный учебник Кустовой Г.И.   «Синтаксис современного русского языка» (последнее издание в 2018 году). По нему вот уже 20 лет учатся студенты педвузов, то есть будущие педагоги школ.

Материал систематизирован, даны точные определения терминов, но при этом вполне доступен для понимания и использования **в качестве справочника по темам правописания**. Этим он выгодно отличается от других вузовских учебников, рассчитанных на более углублённое и специализированное  изучение темы.

**Здесь важно было  определить**  вид союза и временной характер отношений в СПП. У Кустовой  говорится о существовании фразеологических моделей на основе союза КАК,  также дано несколько примеров.

**Частную модель «как только…так сразу»** я разбираю самостоятельно, но там все очевидно, если использовать базовый материал по теме. **Вывод** основан на том, что пропуск указательного слова ТАК является основным фактором для выбора тире/увеличенной паузы.

Comment: "так" это не союзное слово

Comment: Да, спасибо, исправила (обычная схема записи в нормальной позиции так...как, а здесь как...так).

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin ну... объем ответа, форматирование и количество репутации по теме "пунктуация" у автора ответа добавляет убедительности, лгать не буду...